# Using a combo box in access to list all the available sql servers and connected databases

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, forms

Is there a way I can set up combo box in an access form to list all the available sql servers and then an associated combo box to list the related databases? Can this be done in access?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using SQLDMO or SQLSMO (you will need to have it installed and add a reference to the COM component).

[Using the SQL-DMO Object Model from Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155720(office.10).aspx)